# Indicar El Nombre De Base De Datos En Una Consulta?

Tags: jquery-datepicker

el dia de hoy tengo un problema y es que tengo un codigo php que he tenido algunos problemas para continuar y el problema es que tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
$return = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Count(*) as Total 
                        FROM " . s2_ . "users WHERE timestamp > ".(time() - 
(3600*168))." AND tribe!=0 AND tribe!=4 AND tribe!=5");
                                           $online=(!empty
($return))? mysqli_fetch_assoc($return)['Total']:0;
                                           echo $online;
?>
```

mi problema es que la tabla prefijo de la base de datos es s2_ y por lo tanto yo le indico alli que quiero los datos de dicha tabla llamada users, pero el problema es que tengo varias bases de datos y son similares todas tienen el campo user, pero los prefijos de las bases de datos son diferentes, las tengo en forma descendente osea travianf_s1 con prefijo s1_, travianf_s2 con prefijo s2_ y asi sucesivamente hasta llegar hasta la base de datos numero 8 son en total, por lo que necesito saber como indicarle en el codigo que yo necesito los datos de una base de datos agregando en el codigo el nombre de la base de datos que yo quiero!, desde ya se los agradezco infinitamente como puedo agregar el nombre de la base de datos a este codigo

Comment: Es un poco extraño tu caso, ¿por qué tienes bases de datos separadas?

Comment: Hola querido amigo la cuestion es la siguiente yo tengo un juego en el cual tengo 8 servidores online, pero en cada server hay una imagen describiendo la cantidad de jugadores online y la cantidad de jugadores registrados en el server yo tengo 8 bases de datos en mi hosting anteriormente cuando tenia un hosting gratuito era que metia todas las bases de datos en una y no tenia problemas porque solo cambiaba el prefijo de la base de datos y ya se conectaba

Comment: el problema es que el juego requiere de estar reiniciandolo a cada momento y a mi se me hace muy dificil y tedioso tener que estar eliminando las tablas de los servidores que han finalizado, por eso quiero tener 8 bases de datos diferentes para solo tener que entrar a phpmyadmin y borrar todas las tablas de la base de datos, por favor necesito ayuda xD

Comment: Sigo sin entender. ¿Cómo es posible que cuando tenías un hosting gratuito las cosas funcionaban en una sola base de datos y ahora que tienes (¿qué tipo de hosting, de pago?) las cosas funcionan peor? ¿A qué te refieres con que tienes 8 servidores online, te refieres a que tienes 8 cuentas de hosting diferente con dominios diferentes? Es todo muy extraño, con lo fácil que sería centralizar las cosas.

Comment: Hola amigo, jeje, ahora te explico, no tengo 8 dominios ni 8 subdominios, tengo un solo dominio pero el hosting me permite tener hasta 20 bases de datos individuales y me permite tambien tener 20 usuarios para las bases de datos,pero yo lo tengo configurado para tener un solo usuarios y asignarles el permiso a las bases de datos con un solo usuarios, hasta alli todo bien, de las 20 bases de datos que me ofrece el hosting yo solo utilizo 8 que son las 8 bases de datos de los 8 servidores online.

Comment: Es que creo que no nos estamos entendiendo. No necesitas varias bases de datos si se trata de lo mismo. A lo sumo, puedes tener varias tablas en una misma base de datos. ¿Qué es lo que justifica que tengas que tener varias bases de datos? No lo entiendo...

Comment: ahora creo que ya nos estamos entendiendo, yo se que puedo tener varias tablas en una misma base de datos, eso era lo que hacia antes, pero ahora me pase a un hosting de pago, ahora tu me diras que porque no lo dejo igual? pues la respuesta es facil, los servidores de mayor velocidad finalizan rapido y yo tengo que estar reseteando el juego cada vez que finaliza por lo que entro a phpmyadmin y borro las tablas del server que acaba de finalizar para poder importar la nueva base de datos que esta por comenzar, el problema es que cada base de datos tienen mas de 700 tablas!!

Comment: por eso se me hace dificil de reiniciar cada server, las 8 bases de datos que hice me funcionan excelente el juego funciona bien el problema esta en la informacion de la pagina! por eso necesito agregar a este codigo el nombre de la base de datos que yo quiero que se conecte y me de los datos! por favor ayuda! esta es mi pagina http://www.travianforce.us

Comment: Es que no entiendo tu proceder. ¿Por qué entras en phpMyAdmin para borrar manualmente, por qué no programas un script para que cuando el juego se termine se borre lo que se tenga que borrar ahí mismo? Tampoco entiendo a qué te refieres cuando hablas de *servidores*, y dices que los *servidores*  de mayor velocidad finalizan más rápido. Sigo insistiendo en que todo esto se puede manejar desde una sola base de datos.

Comment: Hola amigo el juego tiene su propio script para poder reiniciar, el problema es que cuando se reinicia desde el script borra absolutamente todo en el server y me toca configurarlo todo de nuevo y es muy dificil la configuracion, por lo que yo hice toda la configuracion del server y guarde y exporte una base de datos con toda la configuracion ya hecha para que cuando lo vuelva a reiniciar solo tengo que borrar las tablas de la base de datos ejemplo travianf_s1 e importar la nueva base de datos con toda la configuracion que habia hecho anteriormente,

Comment: En tu descripcion del problema pones `varias bases de datos y son similares todas tienen el campo user` pero en el codigo que presentas de ejemplo, `user` es una TABLA. Creo que estamos bastante confusos con tu descripcion del problema. Me parece que tu problema, si todo son TABLAS, se resuelve con un UNION de cada tabla user. Por el contrario, si son BASES DE DATOS, tu script se complica, teniendo primero que seleccionar la BBDD, hacer la consulta y repetir por cada BBDD...

Comment: exactamente amigo eso es lo que necesito hacer la consulta y repetir por cada BBDD asi me da la informacion de cada base de datos por favor ayuda!!

Comment: Si el script te `borra absolutamente todo` y te toca configurarlo de nuevo... es que el script no deberia borrar la parte de configuracion, o en su defecto borrar solo lo aquello prescindible...

Comment: Pero eso ocurre porque el script está mal escrito entonces. Supongamos que tienes todo en una base de datos, o en varias, da igual. Y el jugador `X` termina el juego, en el módulo de juego se sabrá que quien está jugando es `X`, y cuando se determine que `X` terminó el juego se indica al script que borre lo relativo a `X` (su tabla o el contenido de su base de datos), no que borre todo. Si borra todo es porque no se escribió bien el script. Te sugiero que te informes mejor sobre cómo funciona PHP combinado con MySQL, te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza y complicarte tanto la vida.

Comment: al parecer el script esta mal escrito pero el juego funciona bien osea el problema no esta en el juego sino en el index de la pagina donde se muestra la informacion de los jugadores

Comment: vamos a ver si nos entendemos mejor, en el index de la pagina da la info de los jugadores online y los jugadores registrados, el problema es que yo tengo 8 servers con diferentes velocidades, es el mismo juego solo que cambia la velocidad,en esos 8 servers hay 8 imagenes que le indican al jugador que velocidad quiere jugar, alli mismo muestra la info de los jugadores que hay en ese server, por lo tanto son 8 diferentes codigos php, eso yo lo puedo hacer lo que quiero es como sacar la info de la base de datos de cada server en la tabla users

Answer (score 0):

LO primero de todo, definamos el problema que tienes:

- tienes 8 bbdd.
- cada bbdd tiene varias tablas (todas con la misma
  definicion), en las que cambia solo el prefijo
- conoces el nombre de cada bbdd, TRAVIANF + un prefijo

Entonces, tu código para saber CUANTOS JUGADORES estan conectados (me parece que eso es lo que pides con la consulta), deberia ser:

1. un bucle de 8 elementos, ya que son 8 BBDD
2. seleccionar la bbdd de la iteracion del bucle
3. hacer la consulta de la tabla users de esa bbdd.
4. si hay resultados, cojer el total y sumarlo.
5. presentar el resultado.

Un ejemplo podria ser:

```
<?php
$total = 0;
for($i=1; $i <=8; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($link,"USE travianf_s".$i);
   $resultado = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Count(*) as Total 
           FROM s" . $i . "_users WHERE timestamp > ".(time() - 
          (3600*168))." AND tribe!=0 AND tribe!=4 AND tribe!=5");
   $online=(!empty ($resultado))? mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)['Total']:0;
   $total+= $online;
}
echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS JAKALA, AHORA MISMO LO PRUEBO Y TE DIGO TY!

Comment: Hola amigo he probado el codigo y no me ha funcionado por alguna razon cual podria ser el problema no me da el registro creo que hay un problema en el codigo no se tu me diras!

Comment: en la parte de USE travianf_s coloque el nombre de la db travianf_s1 y en la parte de Total FROM s coloque Total FROM s1 no se cual sera el problema no me da el registro xD

Comment: Hla amigo hice algunas modificaciones en tu codigo:<?php
$total = 0;
for($i=1; $i <=8; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($link,"USE travianf_s2".$i);
   $resultado = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Count(*) as Total 
           FROM " . s2_ . "users WHERE timestamp > ".(time() - 
          (3600*168))." AND tribe!=0 AND tribe!=4 AND tribe!=5");
   $online=(!empty ($return))? mysqli_fetch_assoc($return)['Total']:0;
   $total+= $online;
}
echo $total;
?>

Comment: Hola amigo el problema no esta en el juego sino el archivo index de la pagina que es la que proporciona la info de los jugadores en linea y los jugadores registrados, ya he probado varios metodos en tu codigo y aun asi no logro que se conecte a la db y me de la info xD, necesito ayuda!!